# Its difficult to see the html links

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make links in stackoverflow answers more obvious?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33617/make-links-in-stackoverflow-answers-more-obvious)

I am not color blind.  But I find it diffcult to pick out [links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) on stack overflow and its [nearly impossible](https://serverfault.com/questions/148286/what-is-the-best-solid-state-file-system-ssdfs-for-linux) to see them on serverfault.   Could you underline all links like you do on meta.stackoverflow.com?