# Why are the already-voted arrows so bright on Stack Overflow compared to other sites?

Tags: discussion, voting, design

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) features bright voted marks on question/answer, that almost immediately catch my attention when I land on a page:

> [image: SO bright arrow]

I assume that it has to notify me that I've already voted for this question/answer, but why it is highlighted so bright? I can't even undo my vote by clicking on it after a certain time. Does it also bear another role or is there something I'm missing from the UX perspective?

On other sites it's not so bright e.g. on [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) site:

> [image]

Comment: Seems like just a design choice to call out an upvote or downvote.  Do you have a more specific question?  Comments on this specific design aspect of SO are likely to be opinionated.

Comment: What do you mean so bright? I don't find it very bright. Would you rather it remain grey even though you've voted in that direction?

Comment: We use special fluorescent pixels for maximum brightification.

Comment: @RobertHarvey They also glow in the dark, requiring no screen brightness.

Comment: Each site has its own "theme", the graphic designer just thought that's the best fitting color. Don't think there's any deep thought behind this.

Comment: I don't know.. I've always found that the orange theme of SO was pretty nice and that it actually fit very well with the site. It's like asking why is the background white... white is the brightest color! It's just how they designed it.

Comment: [Perhaps this would better signify an upvote?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LU1PQ.png)

Comment: My bet it that some of the [colour of links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33617/make-links-in-stack-overflow-answers-more-obvious) (or all of the colour of their underlines) somehow got into that arrow.

Answer (score 3):

> I assume that it has to notify me that I've already vote for this question/answer, but why it is highlighted so bright? I can't even undo my vote by clicking on it after a certain time. Does it also bear another role or is there something I'm missing from the UX perspective?

The reason for it is as you said to notify you that you've already voted on a question (either up or down). You can't undo your vote by clicking on it after 5 minutes because your vote is now locked and cannot be undone or changes except the post is edited. There is noting attached to the bright marks.