# distinguished color for links

Tags: feature-request, design, hyperlinks

In some SE sites the [links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link) in post are hardly seen particularly in comments. But in some other sites the links have different color and are visible. I think a permanent underline or an appropriate color can show the difference in different browsers and operating systems.

Comment: is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_(web_browser)) a link?

Comment: Well, similar request just for Stack Overflow [was declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33617/make-links-in-stack-overflow-answers-more-obvious).

Comment: I rememeber accasions someone did not know there is a link in a comment. In mathoverflow.net, they have the normal color except by mouse hover.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think it's good to have cross-site design, underline is too intrusive and would make it look like ad-words. Better improve the per-site design and find proper color on each site.